# PInvoke - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I've seen the attempted to read or write protected memory error before. 
Typically the error shows up when I don't set up the c# struct correctly. I do have other calls working properly but this one is not co-operating.
I'm almost certain that it could be both my function call and the struct that is causing the problem.

C Syntax

```
int CardTransaction(pTRequest req, char *ProductCodes)
```

Request structure (I condensed it b/c there were repetitive data types)

```
typedef struct _cardRequest
{
  unsigned short RedemptionNum
  long TotalAmount;
  unsigned char filler1[257];
  char CardNumber[80];
  unsigned char cardType;
} TRequest, *pTRequest;
```

C# function call

```
[DllImport("card.dll"), CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int CardTransaction(ref CardRequest cardRequest, [MarshalAs(UnManagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder productCodes);
```

ProductCodes is null so I just instantiated a stringbuilder object with nothing in it and passed it through.  This is one place I'm thinking could be a problem.

C# structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]    
public struct CardRequest
{
  public uint16 RedemptionNum

  public int TotalAmount;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
  public string filler1;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
  public string CardNumber;

  public byte cardType;

}
```

Comment: `char filler1[257]` is not a TStr because its elements are always 1 byte in size.

Comment: Your packing value is possibly wrong which might lead to errors like this but you'll need to tell us the compiler you use for your C code and whether there are any structure packing options or pragmas in use.

Comment: I don't have any information on the C code. that is all that is provided to me. And that has always been the problem.  And the C# side i try to make it work. it's been a huge struggle for me not having enough information. And when i finally get stuck this is where I turn to hoping that the experience here would review the mistakes that I make :)

Comment: I always thought it was the char filler[257] causing the problem. I'm not sure how i should set up this unsigned char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem is that the C code uses an aligned struct, but for some reason you have elected to pack the C# struct. Remove the `Pack = 1` from the C# code to make the two structures match.

Beyond that the filler array looks more like a byte array than a string. I'd declare it like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 257)]
public byte[] filler1;
```

If you want to pass `null` to the `productCodes` parameter, then I expect you can do just that. I cannot recall every doing that myself, but generally when you pass `null` to a p/invoke, then the marshaller will pass `NULL` to the native code.

Comment: Hi David, 
Taking away the pack = 1 took the error message away. 
The result coming back from the DLL is incorrect though.  
So it probably doesn't like the byte[].
But...the main thing for me is you helped me get rid of the error message. 
Since I get so little information about the struct and function ... you said the "obvious problem is the C code uses an aligned struct".  Since I am learning and stumbling along the way ... what gave it away that it was aligned? There was another struct that i did that needed pack = 1 for it to work.
thanks again.

Comment: Structs are aligned by default